# Obfuscate PHP code

Tags: php, obfuscation, source-code-protection

I create software using PHP. I'm going to sell this software so I need to protect my source code so that nobody can view it. How can I protect my PHP code so that the software still functions the same?

I also need to bind the software to a particular, authorized PC. It should not run on any other PC. How can I do that? Should I encrypt using LAN MAC address? Does anyone have any other ideas?

Comment: whenever I find software that wont run unless I give it access to stuff it shouldn't **ever** have access to (i.e: details about my hardware), I want to punch someone in the face (and Russian Hackers hack a bank)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Code obfuscator for php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232736/code-obfuscator-for-php)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I put together the following list a ways back - don't know if they are all current, or how many are now free, but you should find something useful here:

About:

1. [Wikipedia article: PHP Accelerator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP_accelerator)
2. [Comparison of APC, Zend, xCache, & the Zend Framework](http://blog.digitalstruct.com/2007/12/23/php-accelerators-apc-vs-zend-vs-xcache-with-zend-framework)

Software:

1. [Safeyar](http://www.safe.setyar.com/) ([Best](http://www.safe.setyar.com/))
2. [PHP's APC](http://php.net/apc) ([PECL page](http://pecl.php.net/package/APC))
3. [RoadSend](http://www.roadsend.com/home/index.php?pageID=compiler)
4. [Turck-mmcache](http://turck-mmcache.sourceforge.net/index_old.html)
5. [eAccelerator](http://eaccelerator.net/wiki/PoweredByeA)
6. [PHP-Accelerator](http://www.php-accelerator.co.uk)
7. [SourceGuardian](http://www.sourceguardian.com)
8. [NuSphere Nu-coder](http://www.nusphere.com/products/nucoder.htm?)
9. [Gridinsoft](http://www.gridinsoft.com/protect.php)
10. [IonCube SA-Encoder.php](http://www.ioncube.com/sa_encoder.php)

Another thread on SO that adds a few more (check it out):

[Can I encrypt PHP source or compile it so others can't see it? and how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470409/can-i-encrypt-php-source-or-compile-it-so-others-cant-see-it-and-how)

1. [Zend Guard](http://www.zend.com/en/products/guard/)
2. [BCompiler](http://php.net/bcompiler) ([PECL page](http://pecl.php.net/package/bcompiler))
3. [PHC](http://www.phpcompiler.org/)

Answer (score 2):

What you may be looking for is not cryptography per se, but rather obfuscation.  If you Google for "php obfuscate", many choices show up.  The first one is from [Raizlabs](http://www.raizlabs.com/software/phpobfuscator/).

Answer (score 2):

[SourceGuardian](http://www.sourceguardian.com) will do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Just Download http://www.phplockit.com/demo.php its gives what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Why do not you use [ionCube](http://www.ioncube.com/) or [Zend Guard](http://www.zend.com/en/products/guard/)?

Answer (score 0):

See our [SD PHP Obfuscator](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/Obfuscators/PHPObfuscator.jsp) for a reliable PHP obfuscation tool.

Answer (score 0):

Usually there is a key to every locked door...

So before using / purchasing some of the encryptors on the market, take your time and search google to check if it is not already an "easy breakable" way of encoding.

For example: http://www.kgbiz05.com/decoders