# encoding php scripts on fly

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Encrypt php code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/764927/encrypt-php-code)

I am looking for a encoder to encode php scripts on fly, so that i can request users url through installation file and return a encoded file locked to that url.

I found this after searching on net. http://www.codelock.co.nz/codelock_dynamic.php but it seems they havent updated it for a long time now and decoders are also available online for this software which people claim working.

**/////////////////////EDITED/////////////////**

Zend guard is quite expensive i am looking for something below 300$, ioncube http://www.ioncube.com/sa_encoder.php provides encoders for linux platform so can i use it the way i specified above?

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use Zend Guard.  It provides encoding, obfuscation, and license controlls.

While Chacha is right that it is impossible to make true 1-way encoding, it is not useless.  Your goal isnt too make it impossible to reverse-engineer your code, just not economically feasible.

Comment: http://www.zend.com/en/products/guard/

Answer (score 3):

Encoding PHP script is ultimately useless because there is always a way to crack it. You can make it hard to decode, but it is still very much decodable no matter what.

You must put the 'eval' function somewhere, and changing the to a 'echo' will reveal all your code, fully editable. The only true way to keep people from knowing your code is to never give it to them in the first place.

If you want to make money using your software A) provide updates/support B) Work for someone, C) Host it on your own server, having people pay for accounts.

Anything can be easily hacked and modified, so you have to change your business model rather than your coding.

Answer (score 0):

ionCube offers an online encoder but I am not sure if it is what you are looking for?

http://www.ioncube.com/online_encoder.php

Comment: this is not exactly what i am looking for, the script i mentioned above is my requirement but since they are not updating it and freely available decoders are stopping me from buying it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want [Zend Guard](http://www.zend.com/products/guard/).