# I need to have a licence facility on my web site

Tags: php, javascript, html

Hi I have a web site on my server that is used to plan events, authorised users log in and use the site.  I am in the process of selling the facility to a client 'on licence' But he wants the code/script on his server. Can anyone suggest a suitable way to go about protecting my code even if it is running on somebody else's server ? any pointers to articles etc would be much appreciated ..

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Encrypt php code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/764927/encrypt-php-code)

Answer (score 1):

Zend has some 'encryption' software for PHP: Zend Encoder, IIRC.

Now called [Zend Guard](http://www.zend.com/en/products/guard/) apparently. There's a tutorial on their website. Alternatively try [IonCube](http://www.ioncube.com/).

A quick google said there were lots of alternatives ("php encoder" will bring them up), things have changed since I last looked! there must be quite a market for PHP encoding.