# PHP code encryption

Tags: php, wordpress, obfuscation

Is there any way to encrypt a PHP plug-in, that will still be compatible with many servers. Right now I am using ionCube, for my wordpress plugin. However, it is not compatible with many servers, is there a better way of code encryption that still work with more servers?

Comment: The better question is, "why would you *want* to encrypt your PHP plugin"?

Comment: So people dont try to copy my plugin

Comment: People will copy it regardless. All you're doing it making it harder for people to use your plugin. Your goal should be to make it easy for people to use your code and make derivative works.

Comment: Does sound like obfuscation, not encryption.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Encrypt php code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/764927/encrypt-php-code)

Comment: @CodeInChaos This is actual encryption and not obfuscation - it's why it requires an additional server module to run.

Comment: Make a good license system and write code nobody wants to copy, because you make good stuff and provide updates .

Comment: @Narf I don't count encryption where the key is in a place that's accessible to the adversary as real encryption.

Comment: @CodeInChaos Not that I know so much about the exact way ionCube handles loading of the encrypted files, but even if you encrypt something and then make the key publicly available on your blog - that doesn't change the technique being used, it would just mean that you're stupid enough to leak it. Plus, so far I don't know of anybody that's been successful in breaking ionCube encrypted scripts (as opposed to Zend Guard) and they don't release source code. I don't mean to be hostile and I won't start re-tagging the question each time, but what *you* think about it doesn't really help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Zend Guard is widely used, but it's not free http://www.zend.com/en/products/guard/

Comment: Do u know if it is compitable with most of the hosting service provider?

Comment: Yes, most hosting providers have Zend Optimizer or Zend Guard Loader (free decoders). Zend is most widely used encoder/decoder.

Comment: Uh, most providers do not have either one of those installed.

Comment: The question was if there is a more widely used decoder/encoder than ioncube, and the answer is zend.

Comment: You said in your comment "most hosting providers" have it installed. That is false.

Comment: Actually, in my answer I said that Zend Guard is widely used, though I mentioned that most hosting providers have it installed in the comments. That is my bad, because I meant it from my experience and did not specify that :)