# How to encrypt a part of a PHP script

Tags: php, encryption, base64, eval, encode

I have a PHP script,
for example

```
<?php
$name="Alfred";
echo $name;
?>
```

I used following script to encrypt,(by www.rightscripts.com/phpencode/index.php)

```
<?php 
eval(gzinflate(str_rot13(base64_decode('encrypted code')))); 
?>
```

But it only print "$name="Alfred";" and "Undefined variable $name".
What is the problem ? Is there any other solution ? Please help me ?

Comment: you forgot the var on $name="Alfred"

Comment: you can try this http://www.php-developer.org/encrypt-php.php
:)

Comment: you don't need to put "var" on php man.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/764927/encrypt-php-code - and remember, eval is evil!

Comment: For php obfuscation, refer this http://www.pipsomania.com/best_php_obfuscator.do

Answer (score 4):

"Encoding" this way doesn't really protect you from anything.

The encoded PHP code is on the server, and so is the code that decodes it back to regular PHP.

If someone has sufficient access to your server that they can read your encoded PHP scripts, then it is almost certain that they also have sufficient access to read the decoder script. Which means your code isn't actually protected at all.

There are a number of obfuscators and encoders which can do what you want, but at the end of the day, all you're really doing to your code is slowing it down (`eval()` is a major performance killer, quite aside from its other issues).

A better solution might be to compile your code. There is a [PHP compiler called HipHop](https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php/wiki/) which will do the trick for you. It's worth giving it a try.

Even with compiled code (in any language), it is still possible for someone who's determined to pull it apart and learn your secrets, but it'll be a lot harder than a simple encoded script, and also it should run faster than normal when compiled, compared with slower than normal when encoded, so you win both ways.