# In PHP how to deliver website to client without giving them source code

Tags: php, jsp, source-code-protection

As in JSP we give "WAR" file to clients and it contains .class files and other configuration files but not the source code, is there any way, in PHP, to deliver the project (website) to client without giving them source code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/764927/encrypt-php-code It's not exactly the same question, thus I omit the close vote ;)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232736/code-obfuscator-for-php

Comment: Please consider using Google before asking such a question. I'm quite sure that even SO has shown you a set of similar questions when you typed the title...

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/

Answer (score 1):

Facebook created a project called HipHop php, a php compiler.

See this post:

[Can you "compile" PHP code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408417/can-you-compile-php-code)

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, not really.

I mean you can compile php into a single .phar file however anyone with moderate php knowledge can get the code from that.

There are also solutions http://www.ioncube.com/ though I don't know how easily someone can get the code from it however I would strongly advise against any solution like this as they generally require the user of this "compiled" code to you their proprietary software to run it.