# File access permitted

Tags: php, html, web, file-access

i am going to deploy my web project to client. Clients want to run it on localhost. 
Is there a way that no one can access my code files and also can't copy it?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It is called Obfuscate PHP code.
I put together the following list a ways back - don't know if they are all current, or how many are now free, but you should find something useful here:

About:

Wikipedia article: PHP Accelerator
Comparison of APC, Zend, xCache, & the Zend Framework
Software:

PHP's APC (PECL page)
RoadSend
Turck-mmcache
eAccelerator
PHP-Accelerator
SourceGuardian
NuSphere Nu-coder
Gridinsoft
IonCube SA-Encoder.php
Another thread on SO that adds a few more (check it out):

[Can I encrypt PHP source or compile it so others can't see it? and how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470409/can-i-encrypt-php-source-or-compile-it-so-others-cant-see-it-and-how)

Zend Guard
BCompiler (PECL page)
PHC

Comment: This reply has a mix of dead project and unrelated projects, and an obfuscator is not what the OP needs to be looking at as it's a) substantially reversible, b) does not stop copying, c) does not prevent use on unauthorised machines.

Answer (score -2):

There are many softwares for encryption such as **Ioncube**, **Source Guardian** 
but they will cost you for the software.

If you are a Software Developer and you will face this kind of issues frequently then you can go for this.

But If you need just a temporary solution you can use 
[Free Online PHP Obfuscator](http://fopo.com.ar/) but if there are many pages in your project  you have encrypt one by one.

Comment: They are also relatively easy to reverse engineer.

Comment: @symcbean true for obfuscators, not necessarily for modern compiled code solutions. ionCube for example introduced encryption with dynamic algorithmic keys into version 9, where parts of the byte code can be encrypted and where there is no key to decrypt present in either the file itself or externally, making it potentially impossible to decrypt in isolation and solving the "static key" issue. Of course a key has to exist at some point (and there can be many keys), but how such keys come into existence and exactly when is up to the person encoding. Disclosure: I am associated with ionCube.